# Json com Array dentro de array PHP

Tags: php, json

me encontro com um problema.

tenho uma API em URL passando

```
{
"id": "1",
"codeReferenceAdditional": "33B",
"isActive": true,
"personType": 1,
"profileType": 3,
"accessProfile": "Administradores",
"businessName": "Movidesk",
"corporateName": "Movimentti sistemas",
"cpfCnpj": "012345678900",
"userName": "admin",
"password": null,
"role": null,
"bossId": null,
"classification": null,
"createdDate": "2014-12-17T18:00:43.3339728",
"observations": "Cadastro realizado via api de pessoas.",
"addresses": [
  {
    "addressType": "Comercial",
    "country": "Brasil",
    "postalCode": "89035200",
    "state": "Santa Catarina",
    "district": "Vila Nova",
    "street": "Rua Joinville",
    "number": "209",
    "complement": "Sala 201",
    "reference": "Próximo a FURB",
    "isDefault": true
  }
],
```

Estou usando a seguinte estrutura em php para ler as informações

```
 $json = file_get_contents("https://api");



   $cliente = json_decode($json);


  echo "id: $cliente->id</br>"; 
  echo "nome: $cliente->corporateName</br>"; 
  echo "cpf/cnpj: $cliente->cpfCnpj </br> ";
  echo "Endereço: $cliente->addresses[0]->city";
```

porem dá o seguinte erro no navegador

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Maps\index.php on line 30
Endereço: Array[0]->city
```

não estou conseguindo converter este segundo array.

Comment: `echo "Endereço: $cliente->addresses{0}->city";`  resolve? se não tem nenhum motivo especial para usar um objeto sugiro que um array mesmo (no retorno do json)

Comment: Não resolveu, mas como vou ler o segundo array?

Comment: Teria em exemplo, sou iniciante em json

Comment: Mas nem tem o atributo `city` no json da pergunta O.o

Comment: foi alterado, de district para city; é que o exemplo da api é antigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está em utilizar o array dento da string.

O PHP está tentando converter o `$cliente->addresses` para string e não a expressão completa `$cliente->addresses[0]->city`

Altere para algum dos seguintes modos e deve funcionar:

```
echo "Endereço: " . $cliente->addresses[0]->city;
```

Ou então:

```
echo "Endereço: {$cliente->addresses[0]->city} ";
```

Comment: Olá, marcos usei o echo "Endereço: {$cliente->addresses[0]->city} "; e deu certo! muito Obrigado

Comment: @JeanPrado Se a resposta lhe foi útil você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **V** abaixo das setinhas à esquerda da resposta.